# How to rewrite the custom url in wordpress?

Tags: functions, url-rewriting

I have tried to rewrite the url from
http://example.com/club/?state=AL

to
http://example.com/club/AL

Added query vars and rewrite url in functions.php

```
add_filter('query_vars', 'my_query_vars', 10, 1);

function my_query_vars($vars) {
    $vars[] = 'club'; 
    return $vars;
}


function custom_rewrite_basic() 
{
    add_rewrite_tag("%club%", "([a-z0-9\-_]+)");
       add_rewrite_rule('^club/([a-z0-9\-_]+)/?$', 'index.php?pagename=club&State=$matches[1]', 'top');

}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_basic');
```

Comment: Your query var that you added is named `club`, not `State`, you would also need to modify your page to read in the value using `get_query_var` not `$_GET` and your `add_rewrite_tag` call is unnecessary. Also did you re-save your permalinks after making these changes, and have you tested your URL using the rewrite rule analyser plugin? Did you change your links to point to the new pretty permalinks instead? ( WP won't do that for you )

Answer (score 0):

You can create an Apache .htaccess internal rewrite

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^state\=AL$
RewriteRule ^club/$ /club/AL? [L]
```